# Microsoft Word Security Warning on downloading document

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, microsoft-office-2013, warning

I have a java application running on Tomcat 7.x (using Java 7.x) hosted on Windows Server 2008/2012. When I try to download a document in IE 11 within the application, IE gives me the option of **Open**. On click of it, I get **Microsoft Word Security Warning** error. Though the document is opened, the warning is annoying. Check the attachment below.

[Microsoft Word Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nKoj.png)

I have office 2013. I was getting this issue in Windows Server 2008. On googling, I found below links

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office_integration__sharepoint/2015/04/20/office-2013-error-certificate-error-the-application-experienced-an-internal-error-loading-the-ssl-libraries-when-opening-files/

I tried all the steps in above links. I have disabled RC4 Ciphers, SSL2 and SSL3. Nothing worked out. So I installed my application in Windows 2012 expecting it to resolve the issue.

Still the issue persists. Moreover my application is not on https!!.

**How do I fix this issue?**

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to solve this by excluding weak ciphers from my tomcat server settings. Below is the SSL changes I used in my tomcat

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" keystoreFile="keystorefile" keystorePass="keystorepass"
           sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" 
           ciphers="
           TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, 
           TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
           TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, 
           TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
           TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, 
           TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
           TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
           TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, 
           TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
           SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"/>
```